# How to view additional pages under google search result

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search-console

IO just want to show my additional page link like this Google search page result. How to do that easily. I'm using WordPress.

Here is the image link that i need to do.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yyn8g.jpg

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of sitelinks that show up in SERPs: the one you showed and an expanded view. The one that you showed is generated by google and cannot be influenced easily.

Heres a 2009 Post about it:
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/04/one-line-sitelinks.html

And here is a discussion on MOZ about it:

https://moz.com/community/q/has-anyone-found-a-way-to-get-site-links-in-the-serps